# How do I make a comment box, using preferablely javascript or php, and then show the comments?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a comment box for my website. I can make the background and other items using HTML and CSS, but I want people to be able to leave comments or questions, or concerns.

I have researched many ways of how I could possibly make a comment box, how to write it out to a file, how to show the comments, and how to update the file, but because I personally don't know PHP or JavaScript I don't know how to do any of that. I have looked at other peoples coding and have managed to come up with something along the lines of this:

This is for the form, it's an HTML:

```html
<div class="commentf">
    <table>
        <tbody>
             <FORM action="submit.html" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td><LABEL for="name">Name: </LABEL>
                              <INPUT type="text" id="name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><LABEL for="email">E-Mail: </LABEL>
                               <INPUT type="text" id="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><LABEL for="subject">Subject: </LABEL>
                              <INPUT type="text" id="subject"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><LABEL for="comment">Text: </LABEL>
                              <TEXTAREA type="text" id="comment">Comment:</TEXTAREA></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> <INPUT type="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </FORM>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the PHP file (saved as an HTML, for some reason when I try to open it as a PHP file it opens a save as box instead of running the PHP, so I just saved it as a HTML) that "processes" the information:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'] && isset ($_POST['subject'] && isset ($_POST['comment'])))) {
        $data = $_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['subject'] . '-' . $_POST['comment'] . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('HAS.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Lastly, this is part of the html that I first displayed, so that it would show the comments.

```html
    <div class="postcomment">
             <FORM>
                    <br>Name:</b> <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> <INPUT type="text" id="name">
                    <br>E-Mail:</b> <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?> <INPUT type="text" id="email">
                    <br>Subject:</b> <?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?> <INPUT type="text" id="subject">
                    <br>Comment:</b> <?php echo $_POST['comment']; ?> <TEXTAREA type="text" id="comment"></TEXTAREA>
             </FORM>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does the last script provided succeed or what happends when you submit the form?

Comment: Your `<FORM>` is horribly violating your `<table>` integrity. Run this through a validator. Please.

Comment: Really, all that happens is it takes me to the submit.html... and from their nothing... For the past few days I've been learning Java Scripting and have kind of came up with my own code... It works a little better, but no cigar... It at least will take me to another page and in the address box display the words that I typed into it... but the problem is ,as of right now, for me is that I can't make the text display onto the page... then after that I want to change the code to write it to a text document or something and save it so I can write it out to the webpage... so I'll send you the code.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101704699/send1.html and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101704699/send2.html... these are the links to access the files... for my sake... and your sake I removed any unnecessary tags (i.e. div's, p's, span's, etc.) thanks for the replies!

Comment: I mean jQuery... not java scripting... all though... their might be a little of that in their to...

Comment: These are the two errors I got when I ran the first html through a validator @Mr Lister... 1. Line 1, Column 2: no document type declaration; will parse without validation and 2. Line 28, Column 26: document type does not allow element "DIV" here... the other 4 errors are because I did a <b> instead of a <br> tag...

Comment: These are the two errors I got when I ran the second html through a validator @Mr Lister... Error Line 14, Column 2: entity end not allowed in processing instruction }


Error Line 14, Column 2: end of document in prolog }

Comment: Both had a parse error... saying it couldn't determine what mode it was wanting to run i.e. MIME... Don't know much about parse... Sorry it wouldn't let me edit my comment...

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found an answer yet heres a simple html way of creating comments section for your website it contains the php

```
<?php
if ($_POST){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['commentContent'];
$handle = fopen("comments.html","a");
fwrite ($handle,"<b>" . $name . "</b></br>" . $content . "</br>");
fclose ($handle);}

?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST">
Content: <textarea rows ="10" cols ="30" name="commentContent"></textarea></br>
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name"></br>
<input type = "submit" value = "post!"></br>
</form>

<?php include "comments.html"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

just create a blank html called comments.html in same folder hope some help if no answer yet

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using the id of the input, textarea tags to access it values from $_POST. That is not possible. You have to use the name attribute of the tag to access it value from $_POST.

```
<div class="postcomment">
 <FORM>
        <br>Name:</b> <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> <INPUT type="text" name="name">
        <br>E-Mail:</b> <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?> <INPUT type="text" name="email">
        <br>Subject:</b> <?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?> <INPUT type="text" name="subject">
        <br>Comment:</b> <?php echo $_POST['comment']; ?> <TEXTAREA type="text" name="comment"></TEXTAREA>
 </FORM>
```